# editing commits with git rebase

Tags: git, git-rebase

I'm having a problem with editing commits.

I have 2 commits for 2 `.php` files. My goal is to edit them both. I read about `rebase -i` and this is what I reckon is supposed to be done:

- first I change `pick` to `edit`;
- save and exit;
- rebase stops;
- type `git commit --amend`;
- make changes, save and close the text editor;
- type `git rebase --continue`.

After this I believe the rebase stops again and I have to do this all over again for the second commit.

But right after I type `git rebase --continue` i get this:

```
file1.php: needs update
You must edit all merge conflicts and then
mark them as resolved using git add
```

What is the problem and what do I do?

Comment: Yes, those are the only two commits in the entire history.
As for the second question, when I open the file it says 'The file changed on disk. Do you want to reload the file'. Is it supposed to do that?

Comment: Is it an option to squash the two commits into one and edit that one?

Comment: No. I have to change both files.

Comment: Please don't add solutions inside questions - post them as an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you stop for the rebase you have to:

- edit a file(s)
- add changes to the index - `git add changedFile`
- amend changes - `git commit --amend`
- continue rebasing - `git rebase --continue`

From your description it is possible that you forgot to add changes to the index. In that case `git commit --amend` does nothing (there is no changes to amend). In addition you have `git commit --amend` before you edit the file which is also wrong (you have to amend changes you already did on the file).

Try to apply steps in the order I gave.

Comment: I gave it a try. I changed the file, did the 'git add', did the '--amend' and the '--continue'. Then i got this error:
could not apply 21e61c9... second commit. Git then refers me to --continue, --skip and --abort commands.

Comment: That error is expected when your change conflicts with the original changes in the following commits. Call `git status` to see how does it look like. Pay attention to the line with `both modified`.

Comment: # HEAD detached from 7deb658
# You are currently rebasing branch 'master' on '7deb658'.
#   (fix conflicts and then run "git rebase --continue")
#   (use "git rebase --skip" to skip this patch)
#   (use "git rebase --abort" to check out the original branch)
#
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#   (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
#
# both modified:      show-dir-content.php

Comment: As predicted you have a conflict in `show-dir-content.php`. Did you make a change in this file which can conflict/overlap with the changes in the following commits? Try to [resolve](http://stackoverflow.com/a/163659/313516) it.

Comment: Yes, i made changes in the file, my task IS to make changes to both files I previously committed. I'll look for a solution in the link you provided.

Comment: Modifying both files is not a problem. A problem (difficulty) could be to modify in a rebase of the first file a line which is already modified in the second original commit. Then a conflict occurs. It is a logical problem when you have to decide what change should be take into consideration. Git (and other SCM tools) provides the ways to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted solution on behalf of OP).*

I got the right way to do it:

```
git rebase -i --root (I wasn't able to find both commits using HEAD~2)
pick->edit for both commits
Ctrl+X and Y and ENTER
edit the first commit
git add file1.php
git commit --amend
git rebase --continue
edit the second commit
git add file2.php
git commit --amend
git rebase --continue
git push -f
```

Hope this helps at least one person starting their git experience. Szpak, you've been a big help. Thanks.

Comment: Use `git rebase -i origin` instead of `--root`; otherwise, you'll rebase existing commits, which can be very problematic

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a feature branch **on which you are working **alone**:**

First make the changes to the file and create a new commit.

```
git commit -m "message here"
```

Make sure you are on **your** feature branch

```
git checkout your_feature_branch
```

```
git rebase -i parent_branch (the branch the your_feature_branch was forked from)
```

The editor will the pop up with options. Change the tag from `squash` for the 2nd line. You will then have the option to edit your commit message. You can remove the one commit message and update with different text.

```
Shift+zz (exit for vi)
```

If you attempt `git push your_feature_branch` here you will receive the following error:

```
$ git push your_feature_branch
To https://your_repo.git
 ! [rejected]        your_feature_branch -> your_feature_branch (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://your_repo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Which is expected because of the local changes you made - to overcome this use:

```
git push your_feature_branch --force
```

The above command will push the changes to remote repo.

**NOTE:**
Usage of --force is not standard or recommended so only use this if you know what you are doing. It is permitted in this case because the assumption is that you are **the only one working on your_feature_branch**

**I am assuming you are working alone on your feature branch.**